# How to create multiple scatterplots & color them differently based on Day-type(as.factors)

Tags: sql, r, graph, plot

I used sqldf function to join two tables & create a final TABLE to make the scatterplot. My final table has 6 variables as follows:-

```
'data.frame':   11520 obs. of  6 variables:
 `$ DATE              : chr  "01/01/2013" "01/01/2013" "01/01/2013" "01/01/2013" ...
 `$ HOUR_NUM          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...'
 `$ CONGESTION_ZONE_CD: Factor w/ 4 levels "H","N","S","W": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...'
 `$ DAY_TYPE_CD       : Factor w/ 2 levels "WD","WE": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...'
 `$ LOAD              : num  182 171 158 147 141 ...'
 `$ AVG_TEMP          : num  66.3 65.9 66.3 65 62.9 61.4 58.3 56.7 55.5 54.3 ...'
```

i used the simple plot function to get the scatterplot.

```
`TOTAL_LOAD = WE_TABLE$LOAD'
`TEMP = WE_TABLE$AVG_TEMP
`plot(TEMP, TOTAL_LOAD, col="blue")
```

Works perfect! Now, i am using sqldf again to make a subset where CONGESTION_ZONE_CD='H' & rewriting that coad again for diff table(H). same thing for North, south & west too. So, basically creating 4 subset table & rewriting the same code. My first question is:'

1) Can i just output the scatterplots for all four different types of zone by some functions at once? ( i read a lot about 'by' functions but couldn't wrap my head around it to perform this).

Now, for the second part, as i make scatterplot for each zone, i know i have both Weekdays(WD) and weekend(WE) in there. but,

2.) Is there a way i could color code my scatterplot based on WD & WE (DAY_TYPE_CD as factors) (let's say blue for WD & red for WE)?

Really like to thank you guys in advance! Since, i am still a beginner in R & i have checked questions on scatterplots before i post it here. i have a feeling this might have a simple solution that i am not aware of.

Thanks again.

dput(Table)
    structure(list(DATE = c("01/01/2013", "01/01/2013", "01/01/2013", 
    "01/01/2013", "01/01/2013", "01/01/2013", "01/01/2013", "01/01/2013", 
    "01/01/2013", "01/01/2013"), HOUR_NUM = 1:10, CONGESTION_ZONE_CD = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("H", "N", "S", 
    "W"), class = "factor"), DAY_TYPE_CD = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("WD", "WE"), class = "factor"), 
    LOAD = c(181.801152, 170.512058, 157.95493, 147.299889, 140.645532, 
    139.216646, 141.670543, 149.122035, 160.893591, 181.996018
    ), AVG_TEMP = c(66.3, 65.9, 66.3, 65, 62.9, 61.4, 58.3, 56.7, 
    55.5, 54.3)), .Names = c("DATE", "HOUR_NUM", "CONGESTION_ZONE_CD", 
    "DAY_TYPE_CD", "LOAD", "AVG_TEMP"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: can you `dput` us a sample of your data please?

Comment: Learning about dput as we speak..

Comment: i have added the dput sample in the orinal question. was it something you were looking for?

Comment: It's just easier for us to work with your code if we have a sample of the data you are using. Sometimes we can generate data quickly and easily depending on the question, but it's just easier if the asker provides some sample data when posting a q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much better to use ggplot for this:

```
# not tested...
library(ggplot2)
# all on one plot
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=AVG_TEMP,y=TOTAL_LOAD,color=CONGESTION_ZONE))
#four plots
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=AVG_TEMP,y=TOTAL_LOAD)) +
   facet_wrap(~CONGESTION_ZONE)

# coloring beased on day_type
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=AVG_TEMP,y=TOTAL_LOAD, color=DAY_TYPE_CD))+
  facet_wrap(~CONGESTION_ZONE)
```

Comment: This works wonderfully for my data. I really appreciate your input on this. But, since ggplot is a big mountain to climb for me, i will use this as a guide to learn more about the topic. Meanwhile, also would like to learn something similar with no ggplot. But, this graphs in ggplots are fantastic. Thanks again!

Comment: It's worth climbing. Doing this with base::plot is a royal pain. You might try the lattice package, though.